# Knockout.js: including static content INSIDE foreach loops

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

this recent knockout conundrum has made me want to headbutt a wall and knock MYSELF out.. so let's see if anybody can save me some pain :)

As is well documented, adding static elements before and after a knockout ForEach is as easy as:

```
<div id="myContainer">
    <p>Element Before The Loop</p>
    <!-- ko foreach: myData -->
    <p data-bind="text: myText"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <p>Element After The Loop</p>
</tr>
```

However, my needs involve interrupting the flow of the iteration loop at a set point, including a static element, then continuing the loop flow.

Here's a pseudocode-style example. The requirement here is that given a list of 'X' data items within the ForEach, I'd like to output the first 5, then my static element, then the remainder of the data items from 6th onwards:

```
<div id="myContainer">        
    <!-- ko foreach[1-5]: myData -->
    <p data-bind="text: myText"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <p>MY STATIC ELEMENT</p>

    <!-- ko foreach[6+]: myData -->
    <p data-bind="text: myText"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->       
</div>
```

Could anybody advise as the appropriate syntax for such a task?
Thanks very much in advance to anyone who can shine any light on this.

Comment: Do you need to show the static element when there's <5 items?

Comment: Fair question @CrimsonChris, in my case I can essentially guarantee there will always be five items, so NO. But for the good of anybody reading this question in the future if you know of any relevant points of note please do elaborate.

Comment: James Thorpe's answer is definitely the simplest for your use case then. However, if the static element should *always* be visible regardless of the number of items... you'd need to do some more work.

Comment: I've updated my answer so it would show if there were less than 5, but you still need at least 1 to trigger the `foreach` loop.  If there's a case where there might be 0, I'd probably be taking a different approach to displaying the content entirely

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [inline `if` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html#note-using-if-without-a-container-element), along with the [`$index` from the `foreach` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-2-using-index-parent-and-other-context-properties):

```html
<div>
    <!-- ko foreach: items -->
      <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>

      <!-- ko if: $index() == 4 -->
        <p>Static!</p>
      <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

```js
var vm = {
     items: ko.observableArray([])
};

for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
    vm.items.push('Item ' + x);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
    <!-- ko foreach: items -->
      <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>

      <!-- ko if: $index() == 4 -->
        <p>Static!</p>
      <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

As per [CrimsonChris' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655700/knockout-js-including-static-content-inside-foreach-loops/32655792#comment53158323_32655700), if you need to always display the static content, even if there are less than 5 items, you can modify the binding as follows, although this assumes that you will always have *at least one* item to be displayed:

```
<div>
    <!-- ko foreach: items -->
      <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>

      <!-- ko if: $index() == 4 || ($index() == $parent.items().length-1 && $index() <= 4) -->
        <p>Static!</p>
      <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always slice the array into two parts with the normal slice function.

```
<div>
    <!-- ko foreach: items().slice(0, 5) -->

     <!-- /ko -->
     <p>MY STATIC ELEMENT</p>
     <!-- ko foreach: items().slice(5) -->

     <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

You could do this in your model to avoid logic in the VM if you like.  A downside is that you're duplicating the contents of the foreach twice; that could be moved into a template to avoid the issue.

Comment: Correct when the the static element should *always* be visible regardless of the number of items.